# Python file after converting it to an application Apk Bi telefonê naxebite

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I have been trying to convert a Python file to an APK application for a while, and when I finish converting it using the Buildozer tool and install it on Android devices, it does not work. Does anyone have a solution?

I hope to respond to the inquiry as soon as possible please